# typescript type check is misleading, typescript didn't report this type error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Conflict with definition but no error make me misleading

```
type Ttest = 'a' | 'b'
function test1(k: Ttest, p: number | string){
  let aa: {a: number, b: string} = {a: 1, b: "2"};
// no error but conflict with definition that b should not be number 
  aa = {
    ...aa,
    [k]: p
  }
//  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'. {why aa[k] is never， expect is string|number}
//  aa[k] = p
}

test1('b', 10);
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngaWHAzlA3gKCjqByAQTygF58iAabXPAIWLLr0wF9N3MAzMEAYwBcAlgHsQUAKoAFACIEAKgFEA%20gGU58hQAoA1gC5yeAD5MKUAG77wEAEbAAToZT87gkAHMAlBmo4ANsH4oABMAQ34Q0gwAbXgkVAA6WgBdfQAiAEZU0xjEZBR4ghSodJYAbh9gsJCo7STIswq7ALA7MVDw8pYgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
enum ETest{
  'A' = 'A';
  'B' = 'B';
}
interface State{
  [ETest.A]: string;
  [ETest.B]: number;
}
function setValByKey<T extends ETest>(k: T; v: State[T]){
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Conflict with definition but no error
test1('b', 10);
```

for the above error, your input `k` is defined to be of type `Ttset` which can only be `'a'` or `'b'` as defined above. Since your input is `'b'` which is indeed considered a subset of type `Ttset`, therefore it does not throw any error.

Add on: I dont think typescript will go and check the type of `k` as well as the variables to overwrite in the code.

as for the other error, you have defined `aa` as an object with 2 attributes, `a` and `b` of number and string respectively, it does not recognise any third attributes. Therefore when you attempt to unpack `aa` and append a new attribute, it will give `never` since it is not expecting a 3rd attribute.

Tldr; it treats `aa` as an object not a dictionary!

Edit: It turns out I was wrong about the 2nd part of the answer.

Using the spread parameter `...` allows you to overwrite the properties in the object.

Comment: thx for your answer it's my fault, but I think b should not be the number in the definition;  The code does not report errors in the editor it makes me misleading

Comment: Hi, I was reading the typescript documentations on this it turns out I was wrong regarding the 2nd part of my reply, It was my bad.
Using the spread parameter `...` allows you to overwrite the properties in the object.